# Does the MRO of this class hierarchy is the same for old-style and new-style?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

I'm reading [Python 2.3 MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) article, where the following class hierarchy is given:

```
>>> O = object
>>> class F(O): pass
>>> class E(O): pass
>>> class D(O): pass
>>> class C(D,F): pass
>>> class B(E,D): pass
>>> class A(B,C): pass

                           6
                          ---
Level 3                  | O |
                       /  ---  \
                      /    |    \
                     /     |     \
                    /      |      \
                  ---     ---    ---
Level 2        2 | E | 4 | D |  | F | 5
                  ---     ---    ---
                   \      / \     /
                    \    /   \   /
                     \  /     \ /
                      ---     ---
Level 1            1 | B |   | C | 3
                      ---     ---
                       \       /
                        \     /
                          ---
Level 0                0 | A |
                          ---
```

On the paragraph following it, the following quote left me confused:

> A lazy programmer can obtain the MRO directly from Python 2.2, since
>   in this case it coincides with the Python 2.3 linearization.
>
> ```
> >>> A.mro()
> (<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.E'>,
> <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.F'>,
> <type 'object'>)
> ```

The reason I'm confused is that earlier on the article it's stated:

> Classic classes maintain their old method resolution order, depth
>   first and then left to right.

**Question:** If the old-style MRO is depth-first, left to right, then the old-style MRO of the aforementioned class hierarchy should be different, i.e ABEODOCDOFO. Therefore, the "lazy programmer" cannot obtain its MRO directly from Python 2.2. Is that right?

For example, on the following snippet (Don't run it on Python 3.x):

```
class O: 
    x = 'o'
class F(O): pass
class E(O): pass
class D(O): pass
class C(D,F): 
    x = 'c'
class B(E,D): pass
class A(B,C): pass

print A.x
```

If the old-style MRO was the same as the new-style MRO (i.e., ABEC etc.), I'd expect it to print `c`. However, it prints `o` (i.e., it's ABEO etc.).

Or here:

```
class O: pass
class F(O): pass
class E(O): pass
class D(O):
    x = 'd'
class C(D,F): 
    x = 'c'
class B(E,D): pass
class A(B,C): pass

print A.x
```

If the old-style MRO was the same as the new-style MRO (i.e., ABEC etc.), I'd expect it to print `c`. However, it prints `d` (i.e., it's ABEOD etc.).

I'm new to Python, so I guess I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, whether in Python 2.2, 2.3, or later, these are all new-style classes. There are *3* method resolution schemes here, not 2:

1. Classic class method resolution.
2. Python 2.2 new-style class method resolution.
3. Python 2.3+ C3 linearization.

Schemes 2 and 3 would produce the same MRO for the given example.

If you want to see the (now almost completely irrelevant) Python 2.2 method resolution scheme, the most complete documentation is probably [a blog post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) from Guido's old Python history blog. There's also an [old archived draft](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#mro) of documentation for Python 2.2, which mostly describes it but fails to mention a special case.

Answer (score 1):

See [the blog post from Guido](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) (June 2010), in particular this important detail:

> The computation of the MRO was officially documented as using a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the classes as before. If any class was duplicated in this search, all but the last occurrence would be deleted from the MRO list.

So you have `ABEODOCDOFO`, yes, but those earlier `O` get removed!

The "officially documented" claim that Guido writes is not from the 2.3 MRO page linked in your question, but from the older [2.2 MRO page](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#mro), in which you will find mentioned:

> Using the classic lookup rule, construct the list of classes that would be searched, including duplicates. Now for each class that occurs in the list multiple times, remove all occurrences except for the last.

Answer (score 0):

Old-style classes don't have an `mro` method built-in; only new-style classes do.

Also, notice that the actual example has `O = object`, not `class O: pass`, making these new-style classes.

And the example is part of an exercise for the reader.

So this paragraph is just saying that a lazy programmer who doesn't want to work through the exercise for the example, and doesn't yet have access to a 2.3 interpreter, can paste this code into a 2.2 interpreter and call `A.mro()` and get the answer—because this case happens to be one where the 2.2 and 2.3 new-style class rules give the same answer.

A non-lazy programmer, by contrast, would want to learn when they do and do not give the same answer, not just count on the fact that sometimes they do.

Comment: @wim The point of the question seems to be clearing up a misunderstanding of the (not immediately obvious) paragraph quoted. Have I misinterpreted that?

Comment: I think explaining what’s actually happening with this code (as user’s answer does) is useful (which is why I upvoted it), but directly answering the OP’s specific question is also useful (which is why I didn’t delete my answer).